# Creating a reference to a value type field

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, value-type

I have a method that can be called from two different locations (call it loc A and loc B). In that method I have a while loop that runs as long as a particular bool is true (call it `running`).

The tricky thing is, if the method was called from loc A, then that bool variable should refer to bool-X. If it was called from loc B, the bool should be referring to bool-Z. X and Z are defined in another class and are globally available.

As you can imagine, just setting `running = locIsA ? GetBoolA : GetBoolB;` will not work, because `running` is then fixed and when another part of the program changes A or B, `running` will not be affected.

How do I set `running` to be either bool-A or bool-B depending on a condition, as opposed to copying the contents?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to pass a `Func<bool> amIDoneYet` parameter to your method, which it can use to query periodically whether it should terminate.  You would then create a delegate like `() => X` for passing to the method.

You may want to consider, however, whether a design change could improve things.  For instance, if this is being used for cancellation, consider implementing the [Task cooperative cancellation pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This is the recommended standard approach for implementing cancellation for asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Thanks! The method is a Property. I just do .Invoke() to get the value?

Comment: I am probably going to convert my program to using Tasks soon, right now it is a lot of bools and Thread.Sleep's and what not.. Thanks for the link..

Comment: @Anders, by using the lambda syntax `() => X`, you basically convert retrieving the property value into a method call that can be passed as a `Func<bool>`.  This says: whenever you execute this function, retrieve the value of X.

Comment: Got it, i had to check amIDoneYet() in the loop, as opposed to amIDoneYet. Do you happen to know if there is a way to use this delegate, to find out what method it is actually attached to? I tried: `if(amIDoneYet.Method.Equals(SomeClass.GetBoolA)) doSomething;`, but it does not work for some reason...

Comment: @Anders, there are some tricks you can use by storing the delegate instance in a variable to compare against, but that's getting pretty hacky.  If the method needs to know more about the function you're supplying, then you may want to consider passing more information to the method (or possibly even wrapping the method in a class to store the context it needs.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. I ended up just doing 'amIDoneYet.Method.Name.Contains("NameOfMethod)'. Thanks again, I am looking into Tasks next.